# Why does bottom h3 title become indented?

Tags: html, header

I add two  titles: "Education" & "My Hobbies"

Why are they not aligned?

I have went thru the code and managed to fix some nesting list issues but that did not fix above problem.

```
<body>
    <h1>Vlad Myshchuk</h1>
    <p><em><strong>Software Engineer</strong><br>Full Stack Developer</em></p>
    <p>I am self-taught student of programming. My focus as a Software Engineer is primarily on Full Stack Software & Web Development. I hold a degree in Accounting A.A.S. as well as Computer Information Systems A.A.S.</p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Education</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Hudson Valley Community College</li>
        <li>State University of New York College at Oneonta</li>
        <li>Recent courses at Udemy:
          <ul>
            <li>The Complete 2019 Web Development Bootcamp with Professor Angela Yu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Books
          <ul>
            <li>Pragmatic Thinking and Learning by Andy Hunt</li>
            <li>Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software by Charles Petzold</li>
            <li>Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction by Steve McConell</li>
            <li>Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Cragsmanship by Robert C. Martin</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
        <ol>
            <li>Completing algorithms on codechef.com and codingame.com</li>
            <li>Practice a variety of meditation and yoga.</li>
            <li>Weight training and high intensity interval training (HIIT).</li>
            <li>Reading books on psychology as well as philosophy.</li>
            <li>Listening to educational podcasts and recorded lectures.</li>
        </ol>

  </body>
```

I expect both headers to be positioned to the very left.

Comment: Because you're still in a `ul`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a silly mistake dear. You have to just complete

```
 </ul>
```

tag before

```
<h3>My Hobbies</h3>
```

after correct it your problem will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo i expect, there was an unescaped `h3` tag. There's a handy tool you can use to check: https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/

```html
<body>
  <h1>Vlad Myshchuk</h1>
  <p><em><strong>Software Engineer</strong><br>Full Stack Developer</em></p>
  <p>I am self-taught student of programming. My focus as a Software Engineer is primarily on Full Stack Software & Web Development. I hold a degree in Accounting A.A.S. as well as Computer Information Systems A.A.S.</p>
  <hr>
  <h3>Education</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Hudson Valley Community College</li>
    <li>State University of New York College at Oneonta</li>
    <li>Recent courses at Udemy:
      <ul>
        <li>The Complete 2019 Web Development Bootcamp with Professor Angela Yu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Books
      <ul>
        <li>Pragmatic Thinking and Learning by Andy Hunt</li>
        <li>Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software by Charles Petzold</li>
        <li>Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction by Steve McConell</li>
        <li>Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Cragsmanship by Robert C. Martin</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Completing algorithms on codechef.com and codingame.com</li>
    <li>Practice a variety of meditation and yoga.</li>
    <li>Weight training and high intensity interval training (HIIT).</li>
    <li>Reading books on psychology as well as philosophy.</li>
    <li>Listening to educational podcasts and recorded lectures.</li>
  </ol>

</body>
```